# Issue with CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. NET Core 3.1

Tags: azure, vue.js, asp.net-core, axios, cors

I have issue with CORS policy. It's obvious that I'm missing something but I don't know what or why?

So, I have client app developed using Vue and I'm using axios to fetch some data from API. Both API and client app are stored on Azure. It's worth mentioning it that Client app is stored in Azure Storage.

I'm using Vue and Axios http client and for API part I'm using .NET Core 3.1

I'm getting this type of error in console:

> ...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
> header is present on the requested resource.

First I tried defining headers when creating axios object:

```
import axios from "axios";
const baseDomain = process.env.VUE_APP_URL;
axios.defaults.headers.common["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
const baseURL = `${baseDomain}`;

    export default axios.create({
      baseURL,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*", // this will allow all CORS requests
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET", // this states the allowed methods
        "Content-Type": "application/json", // this shows the expected content type
      },
    });
```

Then when I did use some get method to fetch data from API I've used it like this:

```
import _repository from "./IRepository";

const profileURL= "/api/someData";
export default {
  async getSomeData(profile) {
    const fromQuery = `Profile=${profile}`;
    return _repository.get(`${profileURL}/GetDirection/?${fromQuery}`).catch((error) => console.log(error));
  },

};
```

Also, it's worth pointing out that I tried without any headers.

Also, on backend side i used it like this:

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                                  });
            });
```

and in configuration method I used it like this:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

I even tried allowing origins on blob services where I'm storing my static web site [image]

Also, here is console error:
[image]

I really don't know what I'm missing and any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: If you have access to Azure, I solved it by enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir/configure-cross-origin-resource-sharing

Comment: what kind of endpoints are requested by the client? The documentation has this note `With endpoint routing, the CORS middleware must be configured to execute between the calls to UseRouting and UseEndpoints` - so be sure to apply it if it's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I've figure it yesterday but I'm writing this now. It was solved as Ezaldden pointed out.

When I enabled it, everything worked as expected. I ll accept Ezaldden answer as right one (effort should be rewarded) I'm only pointing this as future reference

[image]